# Console application using Hamming algorithm for code bug finder

Tags: hamming-code

I need a console application for byte correction, using Hamming algorithm. Can anybody help me on this issue?

Input word would be for example: `11100100`

Comment: Homework, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace Bits
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string NrBinary;
            int pp, Key, number;
            double x, y;
            Console.WriteLine("Give binary value till 8 bit: ");
            NrBinary = Console.ReadLine();
            if (NrBinary.Length <= 8)
            {
                if (NrBinary.Length == 1) NrBinary = "0000000" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 2) NrBinary = "000000" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 3) NrBinary = "00000" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 4) NrBinary = "0000" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 5) NrBinary = "000" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 6) NrBinary = "00" + NrBinary;
                if (NrBinary.Length == 7) NrBinary = "0" + NrBinary;


                pp = NrBinary.Length;
                number = Convert.ToInt32(NrBinary);
                Console.WriteLine("PP = " + pp);

                for (Key = 0; Key < pp; ++Key)
                {
                    x = Math.Pow(2, Key) - 1;
                    y = pp + Key;

                    if (x >= y)
                    {
                        goto Mess;
                    }
                }
            Mess:
                Console.WriteLine("Controled bit needed Key = " + Key + "\n");

                int[] parity = new int[pp];
                int[] DI = new int[pp];
                int[] CI = new int[Key];

                DI[0] = number % 10;
                DI[1] = (number / 10) % 10;
                DI[2] = (number / 100) % 10;
                DI[3] = (number / 1000) % 10;
                DI[4] = (number / 10000) % 10;
                DI[5] = (number / 100000) % 10;
                DI[6] = (number / 1000000) % 10;
                DI[7] = (number / 10000000) % 10;

                CI[0] = DI[0] ^ DI[1] ^ DI[3] ^ DI[4] ^ DI[6];
                CI[1] = DI[0] ^ DI[2] ^ DI[3] ^ DI[5] ^ DI[6];
                CI[2] = DI[1] ^ DI[2] ^ DI[3] ^ DI[7];
                CI[3] = DI[4] ^ DI[5] ^ DI[6] ^ DI[7];

                Console.WriteLine("\n  = " + CI[0] + "" + CI[1] + "" + CI[2] + "" + CI[3] + "\n");
                Console.Write("Bit with Hamming code: ");
                Console.WriteLine(DI[7] + "" + DI[6] + "" + DI[5] + "" + DI[4] + "" + CI[3] + "" + DI[3]
                + "" + DI[2] + "" + DI[1] + "" + CI[2] + "" + DI[0] + "" + CI[1] + "" + CI[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n 8 bit character maximaly:)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably add this code as a update to your question rather than an answer. And you say you didn't get stuck - does this code work for you? If not, what's not working?

Comment: it works OK, but if you think that something can be improved.. you are welcome to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption  this is homework, here's a [pointer to the general algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#General_algorithm). Have a go yourself, post what you've tried and the specific problems you're having, and people might help you out.

Comment: Yeah, you have a right, this is my forst post here, and I dont have a clue about how to ersolve this, and the badest thing is that I didnt even started to do something, coz I have no clue how to even start... If its anyone who have something about this issue, I would appriciate it.

Comment: Do you know how to write console apps? If so, then that + the Wikipedia page should be enough to get started.

Comment: What are you needing to do? take a sequence of bytes and output the hamming code? Or take in some hamming code (possibly with errors) and detect/correct errors? What don't you understand about the algorithm on the Wikipedia page?

Comment: No. And you didn't answer my questions. SO isn't for getting people to do your homework for you. If you've tried and you're stuck, then show what you've done and ask for specific help. If you can't even get started, you need to talk to your instructors, not try and fake it by passing off others work as your own

Comment: i tried and I didn't stuck..and I will provide you with source code here.. If you have any better Idea please let me know..